# Text field for filtern wont be displayed

Tags: java, swing, filter, jtextfield, jtree

I have a problem with the display of the text field for my TreeFilter. This is not displayed in my project. Unfortunately no error appears and therefore I don't know where the error is.
I have found a custom tree filter (jtree) that would be sufficient for me. I have tried to transfer this solution in my project. But now the text field for the filter is not displayed in my project. But it works in the example. I have uploaded both in a zip file.
Found on the internet: jtree-filtering
My project: UILearnProject

[image]

In the example a simple JFrame is created, where the jtree and its filter are inserted.
I wanted to add this on a panel.

I would be very happy if you possibly find my mistake. Unfortunately I don't know what to do.
Thanks a lot for your help.

The zip file: https://easyupload.io/gk5gha

Comment: No one? That would be sad.

Comment: 1) *"No one?"* To get the question before the Swing experts, add the [tag:swing] tag.  Likewise, don't tag irrelevant things, like the IDE. 2) *"The zip file:"* I won't be following external links, same as most people here. All relevant code should be included in the question. And by relevant, I mean.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The  link gave me a _file not found_

Comment: @Abra Huh .. I did not even try it. OP - that's *another* reason we don't encourage links to external resources on SO. They go 'stale'.